# z index is not working in inter explorer above pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

am displaying a selection bar above pdf file. Here is its link
http://tashen.byethost13.com/flang.html
 It works in chrome and Firefox but not in IE.it goes behind the pdf file in IE.
this is the code of a div and selection bar.

```
<div style="height:100%; width:100%; background-color: rgba(125,55,55,0.5); position: fixed; z-index: 8000; " id="Outalertwind">
   <select id="program_category_list" name="programcategory_list" style="margin-left:50px; width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color: rgba(125,55,55,0.5); z-index:5000000000; color:#FFF;" onchange="showpdf(this.value)">
                            <option value="sel">-- Select size --</option>
                            <option value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="32">32</option>
                            <option value="40">40</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="65">65</option>
                            <option value="80">80</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                            <option value="125">125</option>
                            <option value="150">150</option>
                            <option value="200">200</option>
                            <option value="250">250</option>
                            <option value="300">300</option>
                            <option value="350">350</option>
                            <option value="375">375</option>
                            <option value="400">400</option>                            
                            <option value="450">450</option>
                            <option value="500">500</option>
                            <option value="500">600</option>
                            </select>
                            <button style="margin-right:30px; height: 30px; float: right; margin-top: 5px; background-color: #fa5c00" onclick="showpdf(this.value)">Cancel</button>

    </div>
```

any help would be much appreciated .
Thanks :)

Comment: Where's the HTML that displays the PDF?  IE is notorious for treating embedded objects differently than other browsers when they overlap with other things.

Comment: I'm on chrome and it displays it wrong for me too. Why not just use a static/absolute positioning over fixed for the title's background?

Comment: I've used pdf object javascript library to display pdf inside div here is link http://pdfobject.com/instructions.php

Comment: Could it be that on Chrome and Firefox the integrated PDF viewers are used and on ie the Adobe plugin? And @OriShuss has deactivated the integrated one on Chrome?